# How to implement the same concept in Python?

Tags: python, r, json, pandas, dataframe

[image]

So this is the data sotred in a pandas dataframe and I want to create a json like this (shown below) using the hierarchy mentioned in the pathString column. Please tell me ho can I achieve this in python?

```
{
    "name":"world",
    "children":[
        {
            "name":"North America",
            "children":[
                {
                    "name":"Bermuda",
                    "continent":"North America",
                    "country":"Bermuda",
                    "GNI":106140,
                    "iso3":"BMU",
                    "population":67837
                    },
                {
                    "name":"United States",
                    "continent":"North America",
                    "country":"United States",
                    "GNI":55200,
                    "iso3":"USA",
                    "population":313973000
                    },
                {
                    "name":"Canada",
                    "continent":"North America",
                    "country":"Canada",
                    "GNI":51630,
                    "iso3":"CAN",
                    "population":33487208
                },
                {
                    "name":"Bahamas, The",
                    "continent":"North America",
                    "country":"Bahamas, The",
                    "GNI":20980,
                    "iso3":"BHS",
                    "population":309156
                    }
                    ]
        },
        {
            "name":"Europe",
            "children":[
                {
                    "name":"Norway","continent":"Europe","country":"Norway","GNI":103630,"iso3":"NOR","population":4676305
                },
                {
                    "name":"Switzerland","continent":"Europe","country":"Switzerland","GNI":88120,"iso3":"CHE","population":7604467
                },
                {"name":"Luxembourg","continent":"Europe","country":"Luxembourg","GNI":75990,"iso3":"LUX","population":491775
                }
                ]
        }

    ]}
```

I tried to use Recursion but couldn't implement it properly. Guys please help me if you can, I am stuck at this problem from a long time! Need some quick help if possible! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Will be much easier if you split pathString columns so u will have more 3 columns:

```
World | Continent | Country
```

with those columns you can apply a groupby and use `to_json`:

```
(
   df.groupby(['World','Continent','Country'], as_index=False)
   .reset_index()
   .to_json(orient='records'))
)
```

Please, next time, put the table file link here to easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for answering, when I am trying to implement your method, I'm getting this error: " Cannot access callable attribute 'to_json' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"